# Switch Between Views in Cocoa (not Cocoa Touch)

Tags: cocoa, view, desktop

It seems like there is a lot of online information regarding switching between views in Cocoa Touch, but not that many in "desktop" Cocoa.  For an app I am creating, I am wondering the pros/cons of the methods (and please list the methods if you could), and which one people personally use/suggest.  I don't think that using an invisible border NSTabView will do the trick for this specific app, but I value all your options.  I will be changing the view with some buttons at the side as show in iPhoto, iTunes, and generally most Mac apps out there.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I have looked into using NSViewController, but am wondering what advice anyone has about how to use this/why not to use this.

Comment: Can you explain just why you do not think NSTabView would do the trick? That is the standard method for doing this.

Comment: Hi Chuck:

The reason for this is because I am planning on switching between many different xib files for the main view.  I don't believe NSTabView makes it easy to do this, but if I'm wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cathy Shive has created a framework called [KTUIKit](http://katidev.com/blog/ktuikit/) which was designed with single window applications modeled after iPhoto/iTunes/etc.  The KTTabViewController class in particular may be of interest, as it provides a way of switching between an arbitrary number of subviews.  They provide a formal way of dealing with nesting views, keeping the responder chain intact, and keeping various notifications properly observed/unobserved.  There are also [a series of blog posts](http://katidev.com/blog/2008/04/09/nsviewcontroller-the-new-c-in-mvc-pt-1-of-3/) describing some of the reasoning behind the design and how the classes work (the blog posts refer to them with an "XS" prefix instead of "KT", but they're basically the same thing).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Brandon Walkin's excellent BWToolkit](http://www.brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/)

Comment: @Dave DeLong  As it happens, I'm actually using this toolkit for my project. Does this allow view switching, and if so where can I learn about it?

Comment: IIRC, BWToolbar allows you to build the views and switch between them in IB. Then *I think* you can just hide the toolbar through code when you actually run, and switch programmatically (if that's what you're going for)

Comment: @Dave

I'll take a look into this.  But, in case it doesn't work, would you have an alternative suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

NSViewController will work fine. I've used it for a very similar situation without any problems.